# How to take a screenshot of just the front window?

Tags: windows, screenshot, print-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can one take a partial screen shot in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/404192/can-one-take-a-partial-screen-shot-in-windows-7)

Is there a way on Windows to just take a screenshot of the window that is the currently active one?  If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>.  This copies the image of the active window onto the Clipboard.  Paste the image into a graphics editing program such as Paint or [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org), and save in your preferred image format.  PNG loses no data in the image, but requires more space.  JPEG is more efficient, but can show compression artifacts.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>printscreen</kbd> captures the active window

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/making-fast-screen-captures-in-windows-and-mac/) is how to do it for both Windows and Mac.