# take a screenshot of an application window

Tags: windows, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can one take a partial screen shot in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/404192/can-one-take-a-partial-screen-shot-in-windows-7)

I Googled around, but I couldn't find a good short cut application that would allow me to take the screenshot of an application window( and not the whole desktop).  Ideally, I want to focus on the application and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to take the picture, or some other shortcut.  
Does such an application exist?

Comment: How to do this depends on your OS.

Comment: @ekaj Control-P is normally print, not paste.  Control-V is paste.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for correcting me, I am sorry I got those mixed up.

Comment: @Sathya Yes, it is a duplicate, but wouldn't it be easier for newer users to find questions with a title such as this, so asking the question again is less likely to occur? When I saw 'partial screenshot', I automatically assumed it was always of a certain portion of the screen.. but that's just me

Comment: @ekaj close as duplicate doesn't (always) imply deletion, if another user searches for the same, they'll run into this this & then move to the dupe question which handles application window screenshot as well as partial screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To take a picture of the active window only, hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while before pressing the <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key. This doesn't require additional software, and you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (paste) it to all you want.